# Calculating Estimated Marginal Means from univariate data

Tags: r, lsmeans

I am trying to calculate the estimated marginal means (aka least squared means) in R in order to do statistical analysis for a univariate dataset and am struggling as all the examples are from multivariate datasets.

My design is count data (wallaby scats from fixed quadrats) with repeated measures (samples taken once a year over three years). *I am interested in the mean changes of scat counts over the three years*. A reduced sample of my data looke like:

[image]

My mixed effects model looks like:

scatcount ~ year + (1|plot)

the random effect of plot is included to account for the repeated measures.

I was advised to calculate the estimated marginal means and am using the "emmeans" package in R. However I am struggling to get the code and process right for this. All the examples I can find are comparing two or more fixed and/or random variables so I'm struggling to apply it to my data. I am also unsure how to include the random effect of plot in the EMM calculation, or if I even need to? Any suggestions on how to do this in R would be much appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
library(lme4)
model <- lmer(scatcount ~ year + (1|plot), data = scatdata)

library(emmeans)
emmeans(model, "year")  # display the EMMs
pairs(.Last.value)      # pairwise comparisons
```

I'll consider adding a simple one-factor example somewhere in the documentation.

Note: The *model* is what accounts for the random effect. `emmeans` just summarizes results from a model; so if the model accounts properly for the random effect(s), you don't need to do anything extra in `emmeans`.

PS -- For that particular response variable, I'm guessing you will have pretty heterogeneous errors (evidenced, e.g., by a horn-shaped scatterplot of residuals versus fitted values). You probably should consider either a transformed response (e.g., `sqrt(scatcount) ~ ...`) or a generalized linear mixed model for a Poisson response (using, e.g., `lme4::glmer()`). Such models are also supported by the **emmeans** package but you may want to do additional things to obtain results back on the `scatcount` scale; see the [vignette on transformations and link functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html).

Comment: Would you have any suggestions how to account for a negative binomial or zero-inflated negative binomial distribution? 
I am new to both mixed modelling and R and am struggling to work through adding this to the model.